# How to avoid "other users logged on" warning during uninstall?

Tags: windows, uninstallation, addremoveprograms

I'm writing a program that installs itself in the user's application folder, and adds uninstall information (for Add/Remove Programs) to the correct location under HKEY_CURRENT_USER in the registry.

Even though all registry entries and files/folders for the application are contained in user-specific locations, a user uninstalling the app can still get the following warning when starting the uninstall:

> There are other users logged on to this computer.
>
> If you uninstall this program while another user is running it, the
>   program might not uninstall completely.
>
> To properly uninstall or change this program, switch to and log off
>   each user before you continue.

Is there a flag I can set or anything I can do to avoid this warning?  The uninstall is completely safe for the user to run while others are logged in, and I'm concerned that this could throw less tech-savvy users.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have too much time right now, but you can investigate a per-user installation:

- [Per-Machine vs. Per-User Installations](http://www.indigorose.com/webhelp/sufwi/Concepts/Per-Machine_vs._Per-User_Installations.htm)
- [Authoring a single package for Per-User or Per-Machine Installation context in Windows 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2009/09/02/authoring-a-single-package-for-per-user-or-per-machine-installation-context-in-windows-7.aspx)
- [Installation Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd765197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [ALLUSERS property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: The application is already installed per-user.  As I mentioned above, the app is installed to the user's application folder (c:\users\<username>\AppData\Local\...).  Every portion of the application install is done to user-specific locations.  There's nothing about the installed application (or its removal) that could impact another user of the machine.